# Error: Duplicate HTML elements in Jekyll when JavaScript is embedded

Tags: javascript, html, github, jekyll, github-pages

I am facing issues with embedded JavaScript for p5js and Table of Contents using jQuery in my Jekyll site. Jekyll renders 2 different elements - 1 element is non-functional and the other element works perfectly fine.

The page is unintentionally duplicating the JavaScript element. You can view the results on the site: [P5js.](https://fallinginenigma.github.io/p5js/) and a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYj15.png)

How do I correct this error from JavaScript creating two different HTML elements?

The source code is on GitHub at [Fallinginenigma](https://github.com/fallinginenigma/fallinginenigma.github.io)

JavaScript code being use on the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="simple_sketch.js"></script>
```

The rendered HTML site has two elements:

```
    <div id="simple-sketch-holder">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/posts/p5js/1.js"></script>
<canvas id="defaultCanvas0" style="width: 710px; height: 400px;" width="710" height="400"></canvas><canvas id="defaultCanvas1" style="width: 710px; height: 400px;" width="710" height="400"></canvas></div>
```

Comment: There is no question. It's a statement

Also  an advise if you want people to reply is to have everything they need at one place

Here we need to click on 6 different links, people will likely be discouraged

Comment: Thanks @NathanGouy for the advice. Will edit the question to make it more concise.